# Difference between two dates with different years

Tags: java, date, time

I want to calculate the difference between 2 dates with different years, in seconds. I do it like this:

```
public static int dateDifference(Date d1, Date d2){
    return (int) (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
}
```

The problem is that when I run this for example for these dates:

```
d1 = Tue Nov 17 14:18:20 GMT+01:00 2015
d2 = Fri Nov 28 15:37:50 GMT+02:00 2016
```

I get `-169191300` as a result.

But when the years are the same I get the right result, `954959013`.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: I recommend looking at [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or `java.time` in java 8 for any time-related operations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use a `long` instead of an `int`.

```
public static long dateDifference(Date d1, Date d2){
    return (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
}
```

`getTime()` returns a `long` because the result can be greater than an integer. When you cast a long greater than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) to an integer you get an [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and the value can turn negative.